# Displaying duration of FLV with AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flv

I am trying to show the duration of an FLV movie with AS3. I keep getting a Metadata error. Code below. Thanks.

```
    stop();


// Video setup -----------------------------------------------/
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
nc.connect(null);

var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);
ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onStatus);
ns.client = this;
video.attachNetStream(ns);

function onStatus(e:Object):void
{
    if(e.info.code == "NetStream.Play.Start" ||
       e.info.code == "NetStream.Buffer.Full") empty.visible = false;   

    else if(e.info.code == "NetStream.Buffer.Empty") empty.visible = true;

    else if(e.info.code == "NetStream.Play.Stop") ns.seek(0);   
}

// Get duration ---------------------------------------------/

var dur:Number;
var duration:Number;

function onMetaData(meta:Object)
{
    dur = meta.duration;
}

// Play the video -------------------------------------------/
ns.play("http://adobe.edgeboss.net/download/adobe/adobetv/flasher_magazine/issue_1/issue1.mp4");

// Progress bar ---------------------------------------------/
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);

thebar.progress.scaleX = 0;

function loop(e:Event):void
{
    thebar.loaded.scaleX = ns.bytesLoaded / ns.bytesTotal;
    if(dur)
    {
        thebar.progress.scaleX = ns.time / dur;
    }

}

thebar.loaded.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, seekTo);


thebar.loaded.buttonMode = true;
thebar.progress.mouseEnabled = false;

function seekTo(e:Event):void
{
    ns.seek((thebar.track.mouseX/thebar.track.width) * dur);
}


// play/pause control ---------------------------------------------/
playPause.buttonMode = true;
playPause.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playPauseClick);
playPause.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, playPauseOver);
playPause.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, playPauseOut);

function playPauseClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var c:MovieClip = playPause;
    if(c.currentFrame == 10)
    {
        c.gotoAndStop(30);
        ns.pause();
    }
    else if(c.currentFrame == 30)
    {
        c.gotoAndStop(10);
        ns.resume();
    }
}

function playPauseOver(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var c:MovieClip = playPause;
    if(c.currentFrame == 1)
    {
        c.gotoAndStop(10);
    }
    else if(c.currentFrame == 20)
    {
        c.gotoAndStop(30);
    }
}

function playPauseOut(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var c:MovieClip = playPause;
    if(c.currentFrame == 10)
    {
        c.gotoAndStop(1);
    }
    else if(c.currentFrame == 30)
    {
        c.gotoAndStop(20);
    }
}

// Timer -----------------------------------------------/

var time_interval:Number = setInterval(checkTime, 500, ns);
function checkTime(myVideo_ns:NetStream) {
var ns_seconds:Number = myVideo_ns.time;
var minutes:Number = Math.floor(ns_seconds/60);
var seconds = Math.floor(ns_seconds%60)
if (seconds<10) {
seconds = ("0"+seconds);
}
time_txt.text = minutes+":"+seconds;
}; 

//non working duration code
ns.onMetaData = function(metadata) {
    duration = metadata.duration;
    var dur_seconds:Number = duration;
    var minutes_dspl = Math.floor(dur_seconds/60);
    var seconds_dspl = Math.floor(dur_seconds%60);
    if (minutes_dspl<10) {
        minutes_dspl = ("0"+minutes_dspl);
    }
    if (seconds_dspl<10) {
        seconds_dspl = ("0"+seconds_dspl);
    }
    duration_txt.text = minutes_dspl+":"+seconds_dspl;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've assigned the netStream client to be *this*, so you need to add the onMetaData method to *this* as well.

change the //non working duration code to

```
function onMetaData(metadata:Object) {
    duration = metadata.duration;
    var dur_seconds:Number = duration;
    var minutes_dspl = Math.floor(dur_seconds/60);
    var seconds_dspl = Math.floor(dur_seconds%60);
    if (minutes_dspl<10) {
        minutes_dspl = ("0"+minutes_dspl);
    }
    if (seconds_dspl<10) {
        seconds_dspl = ("0"+seconds_dspl);
    }
    duration_txt.text = minutes_dspl+":"+seconds_dspl;
};
```

and remove the previous onMetaData Function

Answer (score 0):

You did not post the error, but I will assume the error is due to your encoding of the video.
The metadata has to be encoded in the header of the video